# How to render multiple forms with different data in django view

Tags: django, forms

I have an attendance model using which I want to mark attendance of a list of users for a particular day. But I can't figure out how should I build the view that allows me to render a html table of users with their corresponding attendance form in one column of table in the template.
My model for attendance:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    ATTENDANCE_TYPES = (
        ('present', 'Present'),
        ('absent', 'Absent'),
    )
    date = models.DateField("Date")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='attendances_taken')
    is_present = models.BooleanField(default='True')
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='course_attendances')
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom,related_name='student_attendance')
```

Comment: and what have you tried? Start bu wrapping your [model into a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) and render it in a simple view. There you should have a better perspective of how to do it.

Comment: I have built a basic view which allows to create attendance objects individually for a user but what i really want is that only a checkbox of 'is_present' field be rendered for every student and the teacher just deselects the checkbox for the absent student. Here I am unable to figure out how I should render the form with only checkbox and a save button to save the attendance for all students in one go.